# Codeigniter JOIN dont back db result

Tags: codeigniter

Codeigniter dont back database result. 
Database table "Category" and "Sub Category"

DB Shema:

```
Categor
-----------------------------
ID     Name 
----------------------------
1      Fishing
2      Hunting
3      Test Category

Sub_category
-----------------------------
ID     cat_id      name
----------------------------
1      1          Fishing rod
2      2          Hunting ammunition
3      3          Test sub category
```

I want list all sub category for some category. When some1 click on Fishing category i want show all sub category for fishing. My code is this:

```
  Controller:
       public function get_sub_category($id = 0)
        {
            $this->load->model('front_m');    
            $data['sub_cat'] = $this->front_m->show_sub_cat($id);          
            $this->template->set_theme('zend')->set_layout('front.html')
                           ->build('sub_category',$data); 
    }
  MODEL:

    public function show_sub_cat($id=0)
{
    $this->query = $this->db->select('*');
    $this->query = $this->db->from('category');
            $this->query = $this->db->where('id='.$id');
    $this->query = $this->db->join('sub_category', 'sub_category.cat_id=category.id');
    $this->query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM category');
    $this->query = $this->db->get();

    if ($this->query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $this->query->result();
    }
    return $this->query ;       
}
```

What is wron i all time have DB error or blanko page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it sounds like your over thinking it, but I'm a bit confused as well.  What I'm hearing is: How can I get my sub categories based on someone clicking on a main category id? If that's the case then your making it way more complicated than it needs to be.

MODEL

```
public function show_sub_cat($catid=NULL)
{
$result = $this->db->get_where('sub_category',array('cat_id'=>$catid));
if ($result->num_rows()>0)
{
return $result->result();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_query  ="SELECT 
                c.name,
                sc.*
             FROM Category as c
             LEFT JOIN Sub_category as sc ON sc.cat_id = c.ID
             WHERE c.ID = $id";
return $this->db->query($sql_query)->result();
```